# JQUERY, PHP, HTML 5

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5

Como é possível burlar uma validação de CPF, sendo que na empresa que eu trabalho se o cliente tem alguma pendencia no CPF, a pagina de venda não permite prosseguir. Ja por outros meios, tem um ou dois funcionários que estão conseguindo burlar esse processo através da tecla f12 (DevTool), até o momento venho exaustivamente em busca da solução dessa questão, alguém tem alguma dica.

Comment: Se você deixar esta validação no jquery é possível, você tem que fazer esta validação utilizando o php.

Comment: Eu não entendi, o que é retoenl, você quis dizer return?

Comment: Existe forma de programar o retorno de um formulário, por inspeçao de elemento?

Comment: Explique com mais detalhes, por favor

Comment: Você vai ter que validar o cpf no lado do servidor, no seu caso no php, um double check. Caso o cpf recebido pelo form no php não atenda sua regra de validação você não segue sua rotina derruba e sessão dele a ainda poderia enviar um e-mail de alerta de que aquele usuário está tentando burlar a sua validação.

Comment: Existem 3 páginas no processo de validaçao, onde você insere NOME, DATA_NASC, CPF e ID,  ja no retorno desta página mostra a situaçao do CPF, se aprovado pode configurar a venda, se nao complete cadastrom, e a terceira pagina tras a situaçao da análise e sugere uma nova análise. Essa parte esta sendo burlada,  e nao consigo descobrir em qual parametro do código.

Comment: Você pode fazer de duas forma, a mais simples e deixar a validação da forma que esta, e antes de salvar você simplesmente verifica no php se tudo esta ok e salva, ai se eles tentarem burlar, ele vão enviar o forma mas não vai ser salvo, ou validar tudo utilizando ajax.

Comment: Mais em qual variável e qual informação ele ta inserindo para avançar de página? Eu trabalho em umas da maiores empresa no ramo de internet do Brasil,  e ultilizamos o oivende para realizar as vendas.

Comment: Explica o processo melhor, o sistema é o "oivende"? o "oivende" é usado pra que? este formulario é da "oivende" ou é seu?

Comment: É o sistema de vendas  da OI, até o momento eu imaginava que seria o link de validação, como se fosse possivel a troca, mais acredito ser uma vatiavel que está sendo alterada.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cEyrDTGS.

Comment: Sem você responder as perguntas do @Wictor Chaves fica dificil ajudar.  Principalmente se é você o responsavel pelo codigo do lado servidor.

Comment: Validação de dados no  lado do clientes so devem  ser feitas de forma simples as mais complexas que possam comprometer o seu sistemas  sempre devem ser feitas no  servidor, no  mais você pode usar um evnet listener e desabilitar a tecla f12, ou  pegar os usuários que estão utilizando ela

Comment: Eu sou Agente de Vendas na empresa, o site da oivende é usado para configurar o pedido do plano do cliente, como estou cursando ADS, caso eu resolva essa falha de segurança, vou conquistar a tal sonhada vaga no setor de desenvolvimento. Como funciona o sistema: primeiro é identificado o setor do cliente depois o Estado tipo da campanha e CPF, logo após vem essas paginas de consulta de análise de crédito, onde em alguma variável esses colegas de trabalho edita o valor e consegue burla a analise de crédito. Passando dessa parte eu posso fechar a venda sussegadamente @Wictor Chaves

Comment: Com as informações que você passou é complicado da uma resposta precisa, mas o que você tem que fazer é passar esta verificação para o servidor e não deixar ele do lado do cliente.

Comment: Ja descobri onde é feito a troca de informaçoes, ele simplesmente troca a jquery do botão, colocando a valiaçao que pode prosseguir, ainda estou explorando o código para aprender mais sobre front-end. Gostaria de agradecer o apoio de todos e a atenção.

Answer (score -2):

Você deve realizar a validação no cliente e no servidor.

Ao realizar a validação no cliente, você melhora a experiência do usuário com o seu sistema, uma vez que o sistema informará se o cpf é válido ou não sem que seja necessário efetuar uma requisição ao servidor.

Apesar disso, ainda se faz necessária a validação no servidor, para evitar que um usuário mal intencionado se aproveite da possibilidade de burlar a validação aplicada em javascript.